# Can we use a variable to create a new variable in Python?

Tags: python

I am wondering if we can use a variable name in order to create a new variable, for example:

Let's assume I have this variable:

```
 Var = 'Jim'
```

Lets say I want to concatenate the variable with a string, in this case the string is the word `Mr`:

```
 NewVar = "String"Var
```

So that if I print the new variable, the output would look something like:

```
 MrJim
```

This can be achieved in bash like this:

```
 NewVar=Mr${Var}
```

But I have not found a way to do this in Python. Please let me know if you know how to do it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html contains many examples.

Comment: `[f'Mr{Var}', 'Mr{0}'.format(Var), 'Mr%s' % Var, 'Mr' + Var, ''.join(['Mr', Var]), ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [python string interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/).

```py
var = "Jim"
new_var = f"Mr {var}"
```